# question to update a submodule in a submodule

Tags: git

I have a problem with submodule

repo A has submodule B and in B has a submodule C1.

check out A and submodule B along with C1 is fine with

path_of_A> git submodule update --init --recursive

However when B is added with new submodule C2 the command above does not work anymore. B is not updated with new C2. What to do in this case?

Comment: using git submodule update --recursive --remote does add C2 folder but it's not checked out

Answer (score 0):

By default, an update would only update B with the `--remote` option, and only if `C2` was added (as a submodule, with `git submodule add /url/C2` in B), then pushed.

If `C2` appears empty, in B after a `git submodule update --recursive --remote`, it might be because C2 was not added as a submodule, but just as a nested Git repository entry.

Comment: Is there a way to update all the submodule of submodules recursively in A?

Comment: @kstn That is what `git submodule update --recursive --remote`, but only for the `main` branch.